# Make Tkinter widget invisible but still interactable

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a little project im working on, im trying to make a little tictactoe game with tkinter, I'm trying to make it so when I click the button it will Make a X/O(depending on whos turn it is) appear. I've just made a button, but I want it so the buttons completly invisible but can still be interacted with, that way if i have a canvas with the image X/O on it, it will show, How can i make it so the buttons invisible but is still interactable.... Heres my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("TicTacToe")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

def button1():
    print("Button1 Pressed!")


background = Canvas(width="500", height="500", bg="#9EADC8", cursor="circle")
background.pack()


#line = <thing>.create_line(100, 100, 150, 500)

boardimage = PhotoImage(file="TikTacToe.png")
background.create_image(250, 250, image=boardimage,)



button1 = Button(background, width="13", height="6", borderwidth=0, command=button1)
button1.place(relx=0.18, rely=0.18)


root.mainloop()
```

So, I want it to have the button on top, but the canvas behind it to be visible, so it wont be a white button, and so when I display a X/O image then it will show through the button, but still have the button be able to be pressed and have the X/O image behind change. so how can I make the button completly invisible but interactable?

Comment: Why don't you just put the "X" or "O" image on the button when it is clicked?  You can simply use nine buttons for the tic-tac-toe board.

Comment: It will be better to put an image as @acw1668 pointed out or even easier to just change the button text to X or O and default -. Also incase the button is clicked you can change the text and disable the button, this will not only shorten the amount of code and it's complexity but also will meet the need and probably be much more efficient.

Comment: You don't need the canvas at all.  You can put image on the button.

Comment: The question "how do I make a widget invisible but interactable" and "how do I use buttons in a tic-tac-toe game" will yield very different answers.